# Send serial data to a specific Zigbee Node with HA (NXP Zigbee HA)

Tags: zigbee, nxp, jennic

I have a Zigbee End-device based on JN5168 from NXP I want to release it as a lock that is battery powered. Apart from accepting the HA lock cluster commands, I need to send some custom data (some text as commands) for extra features that I want to add to the system. How can I send such data and receive it at lock? Do I have to implement a custom cluster along or is there another way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieved with the **Data Transfer Functions** from the **Application Framework (AF) API** of the [ZigBee stack](http://www.nxp.com/docs/en/user-guide/JN-UG-3048.pdf) (See Page 164).

> The AF Data Transfer functions are used to request the transmission of data, in the form of an Application Protocol Data Unit (APDU), to one or more remote nodes.

For reference: https://community.nxp.com/thread/445724